# form_for not working properly in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I have a simple application, where I have created a form , using the form_for helper. On submission, when I try to access the model object in the action that's triggered, I am not getting all the information in that correctly. Some of the attributes are coming blank. I've already spent a few hours on trying to debug the problem , but invain. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Rails 3.2
Ruby 1.9.2

Code for Form is :signup.html.erb

```
<%= form_for (@user) , :url => { :action => "signup" ,:method=>"post"} do |u| %>
  <p>
    <%= u.label :login %>
    <%= u.text_field :login ,:size => 20 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= u.label :password %>
    <%= u.text_field :password,:size => 20 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= u.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= u.text_field :password_confirmation,:size => 20 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= u.label :email %>
    <%= u.text_field :email ,:size => 20 %>
  </p>
  <%= u.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Code for the "signup" action of user_controller.rb is

```
 def signup


      @user = User.new(params[:user])

       if request.post?  

        if @user.save!

          session[:user] = User.authenticate(@user.login, @user.password)
          flash[:message] = "Signup successful"
          redirect_to :action => "index"          
        else

          flash[:warning] = "Signup unsuccessful"
        end
      end

    end
```

When I click the submit button, I get the following error

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in UserController#signup

Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password doesn't match confirmation

Rails.root: /Users/kabir/ror/mmeter1
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/user_controller.rb:42:in `signup'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"yTC5i0HKltD4z40f0AQhir58CF9Pz+19VnKi3lvT6aE=",
 "user"=>{"login"=>"abcde",
 "password"=>"123456",
 "password_confirmation"=>"123456",
 "email"=>"abcde@kk.com"},
 "commit"=>"Create User",
 "method"=>"post"}
```

The model validations for user are

```
  validates_presence_of :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :salt
  validates_uniqueness_of :login, :email
  validates_confirmation_of :password
```

The source code generated for the form a just before submission is

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/user/signup?method=post" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="yTC5i0HKltD4z40f0AQhir58CF9Pz+19VnKi3lvT6aE=" /></div>
  <p>
    <label for="user_login">Login</label>
    <input id="user_login" name="user[login]" size="20" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="user_password">Password</label>
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="20" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label>
    <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="20" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="user_email">Email</label>
    <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="20" type="text" />
  </p>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create User" />
</form>
```

I also logged the value of @user in the signup action of user_controller, and it showed the following values

```
The user params is {"login"=>"abcde", "password"=>"123456", "password_confirmation"=>"123456", "email"=>"abcde@kk.com"}
The user object is --- !ruby/object:User
attributes:
  id: 
  username: 
  password: 
  created_at: 
  updated_at: 
  login: abcde
  hashed_password: !binary |-
    MzFiNDk4MGRmMTU2OTEwOThhNDdkYzNjOTZhOTFjYWFiOTVkN2NiOA==
  email: abcde@kk.com
  salt: tgCV8xIfxS
```

Notice that the username and password fields are coming blank. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the model code

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # prevent the following fields from being updated through a post
 # request. ie, these fields cannot be updated as a result of a form
 # submittion. They can only be updated from within the model itself.
  attr_protected :id, :salt
  attr_accessible :login,:password,:password_confirmation,:email

 # set the basic validation rules for the different attributes of the user
  validates_length_of :login, :within => 3..40
 #  validates_length_of :password, :within => 5..40
  validates_presence_of :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :salt
  validates_uniqueness_of :login, :email
  validates_confirmation_of :password
 #  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i, :message => "Invalid email"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not post your entire model (it's missing an end), are you sure you do not have additional code? The password has been stored in hashed_password and removed from the password and password_confirmation, and some method is doing that. That's because it is unsafe to use those two fields, because they are plaintext.

So, either in your model, or an included gem does alter the saving of a User, and that is breaking your validations.

Maybe you used code from this page?

http://www.napcsweb.com/blog/2010/03/11/basic-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails-in-case-you-forgot/

And hint: in your form use password_fields instead of text_fields...

Answer (score 0):

First things first. The id is empty, because the object hasn't been saved yet. The username is blank because you called it login in the form. Since you have a login field, i suggest just removing username, or rename the login field in the form to username, and remove the login field. Make sure to use a database migration in order to remove the column:

```
 rails g migration remove_username_from_users
```

Then in the migration code

```
 def up
   remove_column :users, :username
 end

 def down
   add_column :users, :username, :string
 end
```

Now, for the password column, are you using attr_accessible to set a white list? Please post your model code. I ask, because it could be that it's not allowing mass assignment of the password, so it's not getting set.